# errors in numerically integrating acceleration data using excel

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a bunch of acceleration data recorded by an accelerometer. It's a table of hundreds of values in a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwA5q.png). When I plot the graph of the acceleration vs time, it's a sinusoidal [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xt4E.png). Which is perfect, and exactly what it should be like.

The problem is when I numerically integrate (twice) to get the velocity and then displacement data. I'm using the trapezoidal rule as a first cut and the formula I'm using is basically:

$V_{new} = V_{old} + 0.5*(A_1 + A_2) * \Delta T $
[Here's an image of the exact formula I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW56I.png)

I can't figure out what's wrong. I dragged this formula all the way down and the result is my velocity is constantly increasing in magnitude when it should also be a sinusoidal wave. My table values [keep increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fISle.png) and my velocity graph looks [nothing like what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7QWF.png).

I'm not sure where I went wrong and I've spent ages trying to look for my mistake, so any help would be appreciated. I have a feeling my formula might be wrong, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Find a linear interpolation for the line you found and subtract it from the data to get what you expected. Looking at the magnitude it seems you are reading variations around the gravity magnitude (9.81), so, when you integrate, you find the equation of the speed of s free falling object.

Comment: Integration is prone to "wander off" due to small constant errors.  Maybe the correct acceleration is $\sin \omega t$ but the accelerometer has a small offset and reports $0.01+\sin \omega t$.  That fixed offset will integrate to a linearly rising velocity and quadratically rising position.  You can reduce this by measuring the acceleration when the object is not moving and seeing if there is an offset.  Another approach is to claim the object does not move much over the time of interest and subtract a constant acceleration to make the displacement integrate to zero.

Comment: What @RossMillikan said, plus: an error in the initial velocity estimate also creates a linear position drift, even if the acceleration values were unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're getting might be about right.

I estimated the shape of your curve using

$$y=\frac{x\left(100-x\right)}{100}\sin x\ -40$$

and plotted it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) which more or less gives a straight-ish line when integrated. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fs77gcayhk

I did the same thing in excel with your method (still using the above approximation), and I got a [similar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZq9W.png).

---

Another way of looking at it, perhaps, is that $Az$ can be approximated by $g$ when integrating, as the sinusoidal perturbations 'cancel each other out' as they have reasonably high frequency, and medium-ish amplitude. In addition, you have to take into account that you're using the trapezium rule, which chops off bits of the peaks, reducing the perturbations.

Perhaps the effect of the perturbations would be more obvious if you zoom in on your final [$Vz$ graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7QWF.png)?